# Replicate a view inside a xml

Tags: java, android, layout, view

Is possible to generate/inflate a view declared within a layout?

For example: I have a complex layout with a button defined inside and I want to duplicate that button and insert it in a GroupView. Is there a better way of doing that rather than inflate the whole xml layout for only picking one of the elements? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible but you can extract that view or part of the layout which you think you are gonna re-use many times and including it where your need through the tag:

```
<include android:id="@+id/id_layout" layout="@layout/layout_xml" />
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html).